# JSON/REST over HTTPS + WS Security possible?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, ws-security

We have a new security person at the office doing some penetration tests on the APIs I've put in place.

He pointed out that we are not using WS Security on top of the JSON/REST service we are exposing over HTTPS to the outside world.

My question is, 
**is it really possibly to combine WS Security with JSON/REST services?**

To my knowledge, WS Security have nothing to do with JSON/REST service at all.. It is used for regular Web services, embedding extra security elements in the SOAP envelope. 
But, we are not using SOAP for the APIs...

Comment: That guy is worth his money if he can explain to you how you should do it. I have my doubts - a quick scan of Wikipedia states that WS-Security is tied to SOAP and it's XML - no REST, no JSON. However, the general questions that WS-Security addresses should be answered: Is it necessary to sign service messages? Is it necessary to encrypt messages that go through intermediate systems? Is it necessary to authenticate users of the service?

Comment: WS-Security is one of the specs for SOAP, not REST. Is this a security person or just a person with tools that output reports he can't understand? @Sven is right, have him explain what you should do. And please add some details to your question, I'm also curious.